# Webclient headers cookie string formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, cookies, webbrowser-control, webclient

I am currently using a WebClient in WPF to download a file. I have cookies stored in a WebBrowser and I need to get them to the WebClient object in order to download the file. I am able to get the Browser cookies into a cookie container and then enumerate them to view their values. During enumeration I want to add the cookies into my WebClient. Example:

```
 foreach(Cookie cookie is responseCookies)
 {
     client.headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "My cookie string");
 }
```

The issue I am having is the a Cookie object won't display a full cookie string, but only the value portion of a cookie (i.e. cookie.ToString()). I can however view the expiration, name, path if I look at each value separately.

```
cookie.Name.ToString()
cookie.Path.ToString()
```

So my question is, how can I combine those pieces of information together into one string in order to get a legitimate cookie with the following values for use in my client object: NAME, VALUE, DOMAIN, PATH, EXPIRATION.

All I have found regarding this is to use "cookiename=cookievalue" but that obviously doesn't work in my case.

Comment: According to the [Cookie.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) Documentation, this method returns a string representation of this Cookie object that is suitable for including in a HTTP Cookie: request header. What is the exact result for `cookie.ToString()` in your loop?

Comment: All it returns is the value of the cookie, but not the name, path or expiration date. I will check it again when I get to work tomorrow for the exact value.